# Some queries in PDO php executing and some are not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to enter a whole table in itself changing the city variable but when I create a temp table to store data the insert statement to insert data back in original statement not working. Here is the code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnsub'])){
       $city=$_POST['city'];
       $query= $conn->query("create table from_php like menuinstant;
       insert into from_php select * from menuinstant where city='Kota';
       update from_php set id = replace(id,'Kota','.$city.');
       update from_php set city = replace(city,'Kota','.$city.');
       insert into menuinstant select * from from_php;
       drop table from_php
       ");
   echo "table created";
   }
?>
```

The insert into menuinstant is not executing even the drop query after that is also working. Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

almost all database/sql wrappers will only allow exactly ONE query per call. so your `$conn->query([5queries])` should be five `$conn->query([1stquery]); $conn->query([2ndquery]); ...`

**update1:**
You should/could also check for errors:

```
$result = $conn->query('[Your query here]');
if($result === false) {
    die(print_r($conn->errorInfo(),true));
}
```

**update2:** please read up on mysql injections. for example http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: then you probably should look at the return values of the  `$conn->query`. If it's `false` fetch the errors with `$conn->errorInfo()` and output them somewhere. I'm guessing your `insert into menuinstant` query will have some duplicate primary key errors ;o)

Comment: Can you do me a favor of giving an example...I am new to this

Comment: I don't know what happened I just updated my code with your answer and it did not show any errors but it worked fine. Thanks for your help Jakumi.